# how to convert DateTime format [2016-10-05 11:58:04] using DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php

i am trying to display a stored DateTime with this format [2016-10-05 11:58:04]. What i want to do is, display the stored date into this readable format [Wed, Oct 10, 2016].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `date()` function. First param is `format` and 2nd param is `timestamp`:**

```
$time = "2016-10-05 11:58:04";
echo date("D, M d, Y", strtotime($time)); //output: Wed, Oct 05, 2016
```

**If you want to use datetime object then:**

```
$time = "2016-10-05 11:58:04";
$date = new DateTime($time); 
echo  $date->format('D, M d, Y'); //output: Wed, Oct 05, 2016
```

Comment: Thanks @AHJeebon, its what im looking for :)

Comment: Use of `strtotime()` is discouraged since `DateTime` object is available.

Comment: upon reading guides.. @PaulT.Rawkeen is right. But can you give me the exact way to solve my inquiry using the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: again, it is exactly what im looking for. Thanks for the suggestions. I will accept this the answer.

Comment: Thanks @PaulT.Rawkeen  for your suggestion, actually php provide multiple function for date time. I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the method `format` to choose what to display :

```
<?php
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2016-10-05 11:58:04");

var_dump($d->format("c"));
```

look the help here : http://php.net/datetime.format